# How to select from multiple tables after joining?

Tags: mysql

I try to inner join multiple tables (table_A, table_B and table_C) with a table_X. The table_X is selected from anther table (table_Y) using LIKE. table_X takes a very long time to create. How do I do the task efficiently?

Currently, I do the following query for table_A. And repeat the process for table_B and Table_C.

```
SELECT * FROM 
Table_A INNER JOIN
(SELECT ID FROM table_Y where ID LIKE "%keyword%") as table_X
USING (ID)
```

Since table_X takes a lot of time to create, I would like to select from table_A, table_B and table_C in one query. How do I do it?

Several things to note:

- My expected result is three separate tables, not one combined table.
- I do not have permission to create a temporary table in the database.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query returns a result set not a table, and a query can only return single result set.
You will need three separate queries to get your desired results.

If your core goal is to reduce the cost of your table_X subquery, you could create a temporary table to store the results of the table_X subquery, and then join to the that table for your queries with table_A, table_B, and table_C.

Edit, things to keep in mind:

True `TEMPORARY` tables are only visible by the connection in which they are created, and will be automatically dropped when the connection is closed; but will still be persist if a connection is reused (from a connection pool for a example), so it is still good practice to drop them explicitly. True temporary tables also have limits on how they can be used, most noticeably that they can only be referenced once in any given query (no self joins, or joins to multiple references, or unions that have multiple parts referencing the same table).

Assuming you have the proper permissions, you can create normal tables that you intend to drop when finished; but care must be taken because such tables can generally be seen by all connections and a disconnect will not "clean up" such tables. They *can* perform better, and do not have the limitations of true temporary tables, but you need to weigh the risks vs the benefits.

---

If you do not have any create table permissions, most of your data processing is happening client side, and you do not expect enormous results from the costly subquery, you could collect the subquery results first and use them in dynamic construction of the later queries.

very pseudo code:

```
query: SELECT ID FROM table_Y WHERE [expensive condition(s)];
code: convert ID values received into a comma separated list
query: SELECT [stuff] FROM Table_A WHERE ID IN ([ID values from expensive query]);
query: SELECT [other_stuff] FROM Table_B WHERE ID IN ([ID values from expensive query]);
query: SELECT [more_stuff] FROM Table_C WHERE ID IN ([ID values from expensive query]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I do not have permission for creating temp table. Are there other ways?

Comment: I've added an alternative to the initial answer